How can I read a Google Cloud Storage parquet file into a polars dataframe if the gsutil uri contains a space?
I have parquet files stored in a google cloud bucket, I want to view and process that data using polars in python
I am able to download the parquet file into a polars dataframe by doing the following:

I get the files using the google cloud storage client:
files_iterator = 
storage.Client().get_bucket("bucketname").list_blobs()
files = []
for file in files:
    files.append(file)


I get the gsutil uri (thanks stack overflow):
uri = 'gs://' + file.id[:-(len(str(file.generation)) + 1)]


I read in the file:
import polars as pl

pl.read_parquet(uri)



This works perfectly, except for a file which contains a space in the path. My code returns the same gsutil URI that I can see in the GCP console, which encodes the space with a %20:
gs://bucketname/long_path/a_key=a_value/another_key=something_pre_space%20something_after_a_space/0.parquet

pl.read_parquet gives a 404 for this. I've tried other encodings (+, backslash, %2520) to no avail.
Only possible workaround I have found is to download the blob file as bytes and then pass that into pl.read_parquet. However, in this case no metadata is included in the dataframe, which I need.
Appreciate any help, thank you!!

Can you try iterating over the gsutil URIs as described here? You could compare the URI with the one mentioned in your question.

Works on my machine when I created the folder manually to GCP with the spaces, there's no %20 in the id, nor is it visible in the GCP console uri. Is there a literal %20 in the URL by accident?

One way I got it working (whether the key had spaces or literal %20 in the url) was to use pyarrow datasets in between, like instructed in the documentation:
I had a bucket with objects in a paths like these:
bucket_name/key=test key
bucket_name/key=key%20invalid

import pyarrow.dataset as pd
import polars as pl

dset = pd.dataset("gs:://bucket_name", format="parquet", partitioning=["key"])

pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(dset).collect()

With that, I was able to get this kind of result:
shape: (8, 3)
┌──────┬────────┬─────────────────┐
│ test ┆ test_2 ┆ key             │
│ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---             │
│ i64  ┆ i64    ┆ str             │
╞══════╪════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 4      ┆ key=key invalid │
│ 2    ┆ 5      ┆ key=key invalid │
│ 3    ┆ 6      ┆ key=key invalid │
│ 4    ┆ 7      ┆ key=key invalid │
│ 1    ┆ 4      ┆ key=test key    │
│ 2    ┆ 5      ┆ key=test key    │
│ 3    ┆ 6      ┆ key=test key    │
│ 4    ┆ 7      ┆ key=test key    │
└──────┴────────┴─────────────────┘

